# jsoup Document not visible the entire link

Tags: jsoup

I parse an URL (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abjasia) to a jsoup.Document, but when I'm going to get the URL of one link (the same page in other language), I find that that the href is not totally completed.

When I see the source code directly from the web I can see this:

```
<li><a href="//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abkhazia" title="Abkhazia (inglés)" lang="en" hreflang="en">English</a></li>
```

, while on the Document I have:

```
<li class="interlanguage-link interwiki-en"><a href="//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" title="inglés" lang="en" hreflang="en">English</a></li>
```

I'm trying with different encodings but I think there's no relation.

The code used is:

```
URL pageUrl = new URL(url);
URLConnection urlConnection = pageUrl.openConnection();
InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(sb.toString(), "UTF-8");
Element countryTable = doc.getElementById("mw-panel");
Element languages = countryTable.getElementsByClass("portal").get(3);
Element listLanguages = languages.select("div").get(0);
Elements countryList = listLanguages.select("ul").select("li");
String a = countryList.get(0).select("a").toString();
```

Is there some explanation?
Thanks a lot

Comment: What do you mean? its hard to understand what you are saying...

Comment: Ups, it didn't paste ok.
By source code I have:
<li><a href="//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abkhazia" title="Abkhazia (inglés)" lang="en" hreflang="en">English</a></li>
while by the jsoup.Document I get:
<li class="interlanguage-link interwiki-en"><a href="//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" title="inglés" lang="en" hreflang="en">English</a></li>

Comment: I mean, I can see this by source code:
href="//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abkhazia"

But on Document in only get:
href="//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"

Comment: using jsoup it shows `<li class="interlanguage-link interwiki-en"><a href="//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abkhazia" title="Abkhazia (ingl&eacute;s)" lang="en" hreflang="en">English</a></li>` alongwith all other languages

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the code? Not only the HTML code, but also the code that you have written.

Comment: ɢʜʘʂʈ ʀɛɔʘɴ, how did you get that output?

Comment: seems not reproducible. I voted for closing the question. @trivili please update the **question** with all relevant infos. Do not put relevant details in the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really sure why you use `urlConnection = pageUrl.openConnection();` However, in your code sample you produce the string buffer sb (I guess it is a String Buffer?) out of thin air. My compiler is not willing to compile this. I changed your code a bit and this seems to work for me (using Apache IOUtils):

```
URL pageUrl = new URL("https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abjasia");
URLConnection urlConnection = pageUrl.openConnection();
InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
String theString = IOUtils.toString(isr); 

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(theString, "https://es.wikipedia.org/");
Element countryTable = doc.getElementById("mw-panel");
Element languages = countryTable.getElementsByClass("portal").get(3);
Element listLanguages = languages.select("div").get(0);
Elements countryList = listLanguages.select("ul").select("li");
String a = countryList.get(0).select("a").toString();
```

Note, that Jsoup.parse() takes the BASE URi as second argument, not the encoding.

This version is what I would use:

```
Document doc = Jsoup
   .connect("https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abjasia")
   .get();
Elements countryAs = doc.select("#mw-panel li.interlanguage-link>a");
String firstAStr = countryAs.get(0).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you say, luksch, worked for me!!
Using

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abjasia").get();
```

It's not necessary tu use Streams, neither open URLs.

Thank you!